# ListView with NumericTextBox Data Initialization

Tags: javascript, listview, templates, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a listview that I bind manually:

```
$("#List").kendoListView({
     template: kendo.template($("#ItemTemplate").html()),
     autoBind: false,
     dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: []
     })
  });
```

Initially I bind the list and later I load it with some data:

```
$("#ActButton").on("click", function(e) {
     .
     .

     var  list = $("#List").data("kendoListView");
     list.dataSource.data(data);
     list.refresh();
```

In my template being bound I have a control that I want to initialize as a numeric textbox.  I was hoping to use data attributes, but it doesn't recognize:

```
<input type="text" name="NewAmount" data-role="numerictextbox" 
       data-format="##.####" data-decimals="2" data-spinners="false" 
       min="0" max="#= Amount #" value="" />
```

How can I initialize the numeric textbox within a listview?

Note: I'm not using MVVM so I was using `kendo.bind("body")` to wire up the UI initially, but not using data-bind for the additional wire up of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm previously work on similar problem, i have a [dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/IVuTe/2) where i have a list view (kind of) and custom template with show/hide textbox and numeric textbox input. Click on the Product Name or Amount will make the textbox or numericTextbox visible, changing the textbox or numericTextbox value will also update the label value as it refering to the same thing on the dataSource.

First of all i'm usually work with kendo observable as vm like

```
var vm = kendo.observable({
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            Id: "id",
            data: []
        }),
            act: function(){
            var data = [
            {id:1, productName: "Item A", amount: 1, isEditName: false, isEditAmount: false },
            {id:2, productName: "Item B", amount: 2, isEditName: false, isEditAmount: false },
          ];
           var  list = $("#list").data("kendoListView");
           list.dataSource.data(data);
           list.refresh();
        },
        toggleProductName : function(e){
            var editable = vm.dataSource.get($(e.currentTarget).attr("data-id")).isEditName;
          vm.dataSource.get($(e.currentTarget).attr("data-id")).set("isEditName",!editable);
        },
        toggleAmount: function(e){
           var editable = vm.dataSource.get($(e.currentTarget).attr("data-id")).isEditAmount;
          vm.dataSource.get($(e.currentTarget).attr("data-id")).set("isEditAmount",!editable);
        },      
    });
```

Create the listView and bind the page to vm

```
$("#list").kendoListView({
      template: kendo.template($("#ItemTemplate").html()),
      autoBind: false,
      dataBound: function(e){ kendo.bind($("#list"),vm); },
      dataSource: vm.dataSource
   });



kendo.bind($("#example"),vm);
```

Then here goes the html :

```
<div id="example">
   <div id="list"></div>
   <button id="act" data-bind="click:act">Act now</button>
</div>
```

My item Template :

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="ItemTemplate">
  <tr>  
    <td role="gridcell" style="width:200px">
          <input type="text" name="NewAmount" data-bind="visible: dataSource.get(#=id#).isEditName, value: dataSource.get(#=id#).productName " style="width:100px"/>
        <label data-id="#=id#" data-bind="visible: dataSource.get(#=id#).isEditName, click: toggleProductName"> close </label>
        <label data-id="#=id#" data-bind="invisible: dataSource.get(#=id#).isEditName, click: toggleProductName, text: dataSource.get(#=id#).productName"> #= productName #</label> 
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="width:200px">
        <input type="text" name="NewAmount" data-role="numerictextbox" 
         data-format="##.####" data-decimals="2" data-spinners="false" 
         min="0" max="100" style="width:100px"  data-bind="visible: dataSource.get(#=id#).isEditAmount, value: dataSource.get(#=id#).amount" />
         <label data-id="#=id#" data-bind="visible: dataSource.get(#=id#).isEditAmount, click: toggleAmount"> close </label>
        <label data-id="#=id#" data-bind="invisible:dataSource.get(#=id#).isEditAmount, click: toggleAmount, text: dataSource.get(#=id#).amount"></label> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  </script>
```

1. The main thing here is that binding the template with the vm again on databound (so it can access the vm properties as well as updating the value from the input)
2. I bind the row to their respective record on dataSource

This is just a workaround for me, i hope it could help you as well